# Can I restrict the amount of CPUs that QEMU can use? Is there a command line option that can be set?

Tags: linux, debian, qemu

I'm using a Debian (CutefishOS) PC currently, and I have one question.

How do I restrict the amount of CPUs that QEMU can use with a command line parameter?

My PC has 12 cores under Debian (actually 6 cores) and when I try to use QEMU, it uses all 12 of them instead of it just using 2 like I want it to.

Can you answer this question with a command line parameter to do this?

Comment: According to [QEMU/Options](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/QEMU/Options) this exists: "`-smp <NUMBER>` - Specify the number of cores the guest is permitted to use". Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: @harrymc Yes! Could you make that an answer though, please?

Update: It STILL uses all 12 (actually 6) cores... What I mean by this is that when QEMU is running, all 12 (6) cores are in use, no matter what parameter I use.

Comment: Are you perhaps concerned about affinity/delegating certain cores to the guest?

Comment: @Daniel B What does that mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The help article
[QEMU/Options](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/QEMU/Options#Processor)
describes this option:

> `-smp <NUMBER>` - Specify the number of cores the guest is permitted to use.  The number can be higher than the available cores on the host system. Use `-smp $(nproc)` to use all currently available cores.

Note that the CPU of a virtual machine is an *emulated* CPU, so it
basically looks to the operating system as a separate process or
thread.
This is why the number can go higher than the physical number of
cores, as the processes/threads will just take turns with the
physical cores according to the scheduler algorithms of the
operating system.

Note also the scheduler will not necessarily assign the same
physical CPU again to the same process/thread, so it may look
like all the CPUs are used, because a time-s;ice is counted
in milliseconds.

Comment: Check the clarification in the question...

Comment: This might be only because what you see is a summary of what happened in the computer over a certain time-segment. You're not seeing a real-time situation. Because the CPU processes/threads are switching CPUs frequently, it will look like all of them are working over a time period. In real-time, only 2 out of 12 will be used at any one time. Also note that the parent QEMU process also exists and is also doing stuff at the same time, while using other cores than these 2.

Comment: Oh, makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned with the actual processors used by your virtual machine, I suggest tackling your issue with `taskset`. [Debian manpage for taskset](https://manpages.debian.org/bookworm/util-linux/taskset.1.en.html).

Get the process ID of qemu via e.g. `ps aux | grep qemu-system-x86_64`. In my test it was 9123.

use it in taskset like this (as root/with sudo): `taskset -c -p 0-2,6-8 9123`

This limits the process-ID and corresponding threads to using CPU cores 0,1,2,7,8,9.

I use this range to show how to specify separate ranges for one process.

I use `-c` to specify the cores as numbers instead of a bitmask which for me is unintuitive in desktop use.

I use `-p` to use an existing process id since I usually adjust the cores, when the program is already running.